# Is there anyway to find out if an array has any element of type int (numeric)

Tags: php, arrays

So i have this string type variable like

`$str = "does this string have the number 123"`

Then i `explod` it to `$exploded`

Now how can i find if there is an numeric element in array `$exploded`??

Or simply find out if is there a number in the string `$a`??

Comment: Loop over the array and test each occurance [`is_numeric()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: you can use regex here.

Comment: like: https://3v4l.org/aLZlc